# Dynamic dropdown with hardcoded choice

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, drop-down-menu, hardcoded

I've been searching on the site (and through Google) but I guess I might be misphrasing my problem.

Here's my situation. I have this dynamically populated dropdown (which is working) that can, in some occasions, receive a value to display a specific option.

```
    echo "<td><select id='bids_id' class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all normalselect' style='width: 150px'>";
    $sql = "SELECT
                `bids`.`id`,
                `bids`.`name`
            FROM
                `bids`
                Inner Join `bids_primes` ON `bids`.`id` = `bids_primes`.`bid_id`
            WHERE
                `bids_primes`.`tid` = '". $db->real_escape_string($_SESSION['Current_TID']) ."'
            ";
    $querybids = $db->query($sql);
while($row = $querybids->fetch_object()) {
    echo "<option value='{$row->id}' ". ($row->id == $timeinfo->relatedbid ? "selected=selected" : "") .">{$row->name}</option>";
}
```

Now the only thing I'm trying to do, with no luck, is to add a "hardcoded" choice with the values of '0' and a text of 'Other'. This choice should also be  bound by the same mechanic (where it can be specified to be pre-selected).

[UPDATE]
So to help out with the context of my situation, here is the code that preceeds this part. This is a PHP file that is called from within another PHP file (same principal as a div). The PHP in question is an entry form that is used both for new data entry and modification of existing data (and this interacts with the database).

The script knows if it's adding or modifying based on the "entry_id" it receives as paramater, a bit like a function would.

```
    if(isset($_REQUEST['entry']) && ($_REQUEST['entry'] > 0)) {
    $sql = "SELECT
                `cap_plan`.`entryid`,
                `cap_plan`.`startdate`,
                `bids`.`name`,
                `cap_plan`.`duration`,
                `cap_plan`.`description`,
                `cap_plan`.`relatedbid`
            FROM
                `cap_plan`
            LEFT JOIN
                `bids` ON `cap_plan`.`relatedbid` = `bids`.`id`
            WHERE
                `cap_plan`.`entryid` = '". $db->real_escape_string($_REQUEST['entry']) ."'
            ";
    $timeinfo = $db->query($sql)->fetch_object();
} 
    else {
        $timeinfo = new StdClass();
        $timeinfo->entryid = 0;
        $timeinfo->employee = $_SESSION['name'];
        $timeinfo->startdate = date("Y-m-d");
        $timeinfo->duration = "";
        $timeinfo->description = "";
        $timeinfo->relatedbid = "0";
    }
```

Here's a screenshot to help illustrate it all:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7d5d.png

Comment: Why not just echo the select option before your `while` statement? `echo "<option value=\"0\" ". ($row->id == $timeinfo->relatedbid ? "selected=selected" : "") .">Other</option>"`?

Comment: I didn't know this was possible. Let me try this and update the thread right after.

Comment: Just FYI, you haven't fetched the `$row` object before you call your `while`, so `$row` is going to be undefined, and you'll need another way to determine if the "Other" option is to be selected.

Comment: Thumbs up for the first solution as it solved my issue. Now, for that last hint, I'll have to play around and do some research I guess to make sure it'll work properly.


Do you suggest I go with a format similar to this:

$row = $querybids->fetch_object();
echo "<option value=\"0\" ". ($row->id == $timeinfo->relatedbid ? "selected=selected" : "") .">Other</option>";
while($row) {
 echo "<option value='{$row->id}' ". ($row->id == $timeinfo->relatedbid ? "selected=selected" : "") .">{$row->name}</option>";
}

Comment: I get the feeling that you don't have the best grasp on how PHP/MySQL interact and you're grasping at straws; you're just fetching the first row returned, which may or may not be what you want. I honestly can't tell what exactly you're trying to do here. You just need a way to tell whether or not the "other" option is to be selected. Maybe an `if` statement that detects the value 0 in your `while` loop and sets a flag?

Comment: As far as having a grasp on the interaction, you are right. I'm not the most experienced person out there. ---------
Let me edit my original post to give more context.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want the "Other" option with the value of "0" to be selected? Test for those circumstances with an `if` statement in your loop, and if it's true, then echo the hard-coded option.

Comment: For one, i need it to be the default option. So, by being 0, it will always be the first one in the list. Then, I need it to be selected if the database record that is received (for modification) has "other" as a project.

Comment: If CBP is correct and you could use some extra PHP/MySQL instruction, check out the fantastic tutorials Alex Garret has put together (free!) at [phpAcademy.org](http://phpacademy.org). There is one called "Registration and Login" (or close to that name) that is very applicable to what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, all you wish to do is to insert a hard-coded option at the top of the list, BEFORE the dynamically generated choices.

Just do this:

```
echo "<td><select id='bids_id' class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all normalselect' style='width: 150px'>";
echo "<option value = '0'>Choose One</option>";
$sql = "SELECT etc etc etc
etc.
```

Note that you do not need to specify the selected attribute on the first, default, option tag (the "Choose One" option), because it will automatically be the selected option *IF* nothing else is selected. I believe that is what you would want.

---

What I would do, though, is to assign all values to a variable and then echo out the variable, so that everything appears all-at-once. Like this:

```
$opt = "<td><select id='bids_id' class='ui-widget-content ui-corner-all normalselect' style='width: 150px'>";
$opt .= "<option value = '0'>Choose One</option>";

$sql = "SELECT etc etc etc";
$querybids = $db->query($sql);

while($row = $querybids->fetch_object()) {
    $opt .= "<option value='{$row->id}' ". ($row->id == $timeinfo->relatedbid ? "selected=selected" : "") .">{$row->name}</option>";
}

echo $opt;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to put this here:

1. Just because the value is "0" doesn't mean it'll be the first one in the list; it'll be first because it's first in the HTML.
2. In a `<select>` form element with all its options, there should only be one option that's `selected`. If that's true, and you're testing for all options OTHER than "other", then none of your `<options>` will get the `selected` attribute if the option is, in fact, "other". So, your first option ("other") will be selected because it's first.

Does that makes sense?

Comment: I have to be honest with you, #2 is a bit confusing for me.  #1 is clear and makes total sense. -----------
As far as #2 is concerned, I really need to test it and bang my head on this.  Again, thank you very much for you time and answers. :)

Comment: CBP's 2nd point is that "other" might be the selected option (because it is first choice and user hasn't chosen a different option). If you are testing for everything EXCEPT "other", then what happens in this case (where user hasn't selected a choice, so the "other" option -- the one you are not testing for -- is the selected one).